# Is a Canon Rebel T3 an appropriate entry-level DSLR?

Tags: canon, dslr, sports, camera-recommendation

I'm starting photography and am wondering if the Canon Rebel T3 is a good choice.

My only real constraints are that I want to able to take "burst shots" (such as of sports events) and low light shots.

Thank you

Comment: Is <entry level camera here> good enough for <the hardest things possible for a DSLR>? Probably if you're not a professional. But more expensive cameras obviously do the job better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entry-level DSLRs can do burst shots, but none of them is very strong in it.

With RAW, the Canon T3 can only shoot two frames per second and has to stop after five frames. JPEG is a little better, 3 fps up to 830 frames.

Nikon D3100 is faster with RAW (3 fps) and has larger/faster buffer (13 RAW, unlimited JPEG).

Pentax K-r has the fastest frame rate, 6 fps (25 JPEG / 12 RAW), but you might find its tracking AF inadequate and too slow for sports events.

Comment: I believe the D3100 is limited to 100 exposures per squeeze of the shutter (though with a fast card you can just press the button again to continue) -- only matters for your JPEG measurements though.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question: **Yes**. It's a mid/entry-level SLR from one of the top brands, and so it unquestionably fits. It may not be the perfect match for your needs, so if you're *really* concerned, sure, look around a little bit before impulse-buying, but everything in photography requires some compromise or another. This particular model is popular, well-reviewed, and top-selling — so, yes, it's an appropriate entry-level dSLR.

It doesn't have the fastest burst rate in its class, and maybe ditto on the detail at very high ISO. But it's got other things going for it as well — particularly, video and high-detail at low ISO. If this is the camera you're leaning towards, buy it with no regrets.

Answer (score -1):

I have one and in my opinion it takes good video and pictures. Nothing to complain about, except I do wish it had a faster burst rate.

Comment: Hi Robert, and welcome to PhotoSE. I'm having a little bit of a hard time fully understanding your answer. For one, there is no punctuation, which makes for a bit of a run-on sentence. Second, you seem to mention that you have a complaint about the T3i, but I can't be sure if you have actually voiced that complaint or not. Could you clarify your answer, and explain what you do and don't like about the camera separately?

Comment: As written here, I would assume he has the T3 and not the T3i?