# Canon EOS 650D for a beginner?

Tags: canon, photography-basics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)
>   [Is a Canon Rebel T3 an appropriate entry-level DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13520/is-a-canon-rebel-t3-an-appropriate-entry-level-dslr)

I want to start photography because I think is a very relaxing and agreeable hobby.

My father has a Canon, so I think to buy a Canon too... I saw the new Canon EOS 650D with an objective 18-135 mm at a good price: it is a good camera for beginners?

I need advices because I don't know very much about photography and spend a lot of money for the wrong camera would be really wasteful...

EDIT: Basically I want to start with photo of nature (landscapes and maybe macros) and people on the street on the day. The photo will be displayed on my MacBook Pro with Retina Display and the bests photos will be printed.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/what-should-a-photography-beginner-focus-on

Comment: Welcome R.M.! Please see our FAQ on how to ask questions here(http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) Specifically please try to limit your question to a single question per thread. As is, this question asks 1.what is a good first DSLR 2.is the 650D good for me 3.What is the best raw software etc. Also, try our search to help answer some of the questions first!

Comment: @dpollitt I searched on internet and on the website but I didn't find an answer that satisfy me for every question. Sorry if I posted more questions in one... I have to split my question?

Comment: Yes each question should be separated into distinct questions on this website(different pages). You can edit your questions at anytime so feel free to do so at this point.

Comment: Please edit to include specific information about what kind of photography you want to do, the type subjects, the medium you want to display, etc. As it stands, this is too vague for a specific recommendation.

Comment: @Itai I edited the question. I don't want something too specific. I'm a beginner, so I want a flexible camera.

Comment: If your father has lenses, don't bother buying a kit lens. Take time to find out what lenses suit your needs, the body doesn't really matter in defining the pictures you will take.

Comment: @R.M. - In that case your question may already be answsred. Have you read the proposed duplicate? Otherwise any DSLR or even a mirrorless (if small size is important to you) will do for those easy subjects. You just have to get some good lenses, usually wide-angle for landscape, macro for macro :) and a bright prime of portraits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canon 650D is a good camera, 60D is good too... they're all good, you should really decide based on your budget and your needs.

I'm not sure what camera and lenses you father has, but assuming that he already owns some lenses that you can borrow and use on your future camera, a Canon is what should get.

Now the body. define your needs and your maximum budget, remember you need some some accessories too. choose the model(s) you want based on your budget and compare them if needed. check reviews and samples. also take them in your hand and see how it feels in your hand, for many people that is a very important factor.

http://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/cameras

As for the lens. first, see what lenses your father has. also ask yourself, what do you gonna shoot?